# Problem using a React icon for onClick navigation

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-icons

I am trying to use a React icon for onClick navigation to my homepage. Button onClick works for this but when I use the same code for a react icon, I get a blank page. The commented out section is the working button onClick.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';
import { Bix } from 'react-icons/bi';
export default function BlackWhite() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = () => {
    navigate('/');
  };
  return (
    <div className="BlackWhite">
      <h1>Black and white</h1>
      //<button onClick={handleClick}>Back to homepage</button>
      <Bix onClick={handleClick}></Bix>
    </div>
  );
}
``
```

Comment: Show the errors from the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your icon name is wrong. Your are importing `Bix` but react-icons provide `BiX`. Capital X. You should check console why you are getting error. Better way is to click and copy icon name when you are selecting icons from react-icons.

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';
import { BiX } from 'react-icons/bi';
export default function BlackWhite() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleClick = () => {
        navigate('/');
    };
    return (
        <div className="BlackWhite">
            <h1>Black and white</h1>
            {/* <button onClick={handleClick}>Back to homepage</button> */}
            <BiX className='icon' onClick={handleClick}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I am still getting a blank page.

Comment: That worked but the icon displays inside a button. My aim is to have the icon display on its own.

Comment: @transpose You can remove button and use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Answer (score 0):

- try with this :

  ```
  import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
  import { BiX } from 'react-icons/bi';

  export default function BlackWhite() {
   const navigate = useNavigate();

   const handleClick = async (request) => {
    navigate('/'); or
    navigate('/home');
    };
   return (
    <div className="BlackWhite">
        <h1>Black and white</h1>
        {/* <button onClick={handleClick}>Back to homepage</button> */}
        <BiX className='icon' onClick={event=>{handleClick(option)}}/>
    </div>
    );
    }
  ```

Comment: I tried that. The icon is there but it is not clickable. That is, when you move the cursor over the icon, there is no change.

Comment: use IconButton tag like this :          <IconButton onClick={event =>{handleClick(option)}}> <Bix/></IconButton>